# Suitable data structure to quickly retrieve two different parameters

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have some pairs `std::pair<X, Y>`. `X` is unique and will never change and `Y` will be regularly updated. The pairs need to be sorted based on `Y` but I also want quick retrieval of a `X` to update a `Y`.

Until now I used `std::set<std::pair<X, Y>, CustomCompare>` to get the sorted list based on `Y`. However updates are now slow, I think in the worst case I need to run through the whole set to find the correct `X`. Am I right?

Is there any datastructure that supports sorting using `Y` plus quick (O(logn) or less) retrieval of `X`? I'm open to the idea of using a supporting data structure or splitting up `X` and `Y`.

**EDIT:**
Maybe an example will clear things up. Let's say X is a name and Y is monthly salary. So a pair could be ("John", 5000). Now I need a list/set of people sorted by the highest salary, for example [("Mary", 8000), ("John", 5000), ("Chris", 2000)]. Additionaly, I need a way to lookup a person (in O(1) or O(logn)), so that I can remove the name-salary pair from the list/set, update the salary and then re-insert the name-salary pair into the sorted list/set. Updates occur very frequently.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your issue, but I'd say that you could use a set (a tree) for Y and a map (a hash) for X

Comment: Since `X` never changes and is unique you can use a `map`. However, because you want to keep a list sorted by `Y` you must hold `Y` in a different container that can be sorted. You may need to wrap `X` and/or `Y` in another data structure that makes going from an `X` to the corresponding `Y` (or vice-versa) a O(1) operation. But I'm not sure that I understood all the details of your question.

Comment: @JackLilhammers @icebp Maybe an example will clear things up. Let's say `X` is a name and `Y` is monthly salary. So a pair could be `("John", 5000)`. Now I need a list/set of people sorted by the highest salary, for example `[("Mary", 8000), ("John", 5000), ("Chris", 2000)]`. Additionaly, I need a way to lookup a person (in O(1) or O(logn)), so that I can remove the name-salary pair from the list/set, update the salary and then re-insert the name-salary pair into the sorted list/set.

Comment: Forgive my question, can't you store your data and just sort your set on the fly? By salary o any other criterion

Comment: Of course that depends on how many updates you must perform

Comment: @philhimself Edit your question with the details from your comment, so others can see them easier. Will a solution like this help? Keep `Y` in a sorted `std::vector` and keep a `std::map` where the key is `X` and the value is the index of the corresponding `Y` index inside the vector.

Comment: @JackLilhammers @icebp Thank you for your answers. I will test both of them to check which is faster. Good to know is that I need to update `Y`s much more often than I need to find the largest `Y`. Therefore sorting at the end might be faster than sorting every time I update a `Y`.

Comment: Also if you only need to keep track of the largest Y, you can use an unordered map with X as keys and save the X with  the largest Y. This would have O(1) complexity for access, insertion, and raising of the largest Y, but O(n) for deleting or lowering the current largest Y. The actual performance of this structure would heavily depend on your use case. If the largest Y is rarely decreased or deleted, then the amortized complexity would be O(1)

Comment: @JackLilhammers Unfortunately the largest Y can change frequently and I also need to read the largest n entries most of the time, with n changing throughout execution and depending on a few parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that one STL container or some nested STL containers can fullfill your requirements.

But I do think that a combination of STL containers could fullfill your requirements. In my proposal, I basically store the data 2 times redundant and connect them with some sort of ID. Like in a database where you build a m:n relation with an additional helper table.

Please see the below source code. It is only a skelleton and needs to be made iterable, but you may get the idea.

The overall performance depends strongly on the single performance of the hash algorithm. I assume O(1) for operations with a `std::unordered_map` and o(log n) for the `std::map`.

Sub optimum hashing can of course lead to O(n).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>

// Some aliases for easier understanding
using Salary = unsigned int;
using Name = std::string;
using ID = size_t;
using NameAndSalary = std::pair<Name, Salary>;

// New data structure according to given requirements
struct Employees {
    std::unordered_map<ID, NameAndSalary> lookup{}; // O(1)

    std::unordered_map<Name, ID> names{};           // O(1)
    std::map<Salary, ID> salaries{};                // O(log n)

    void add(Name&& n, Salary&& s) {
        ID newID = lookup.size();
        names[n] = newID;                           // O(1)
        salaries[s] = newID;                        // O(log n)
        lookup[newID] = { n,s };                    // O(1)
    }
    Salary getSalaryViaName(const Name& n)  { return lookup[names[n]].second; } // O(1) O(1)
    Name getNamebySalary(const Salary& s) { return lookup[salaries[s]].first; } // O(1) O(log n)
};
// Some test code
int main() {

    Employees employees{};
    // Populate struct
    employees.add("John", 456);
    employees.add("Paul", 345);
    employees.add("Ringo", 234);
    employees.add("George", 123);

    // Iterate
    for (const auto& [salary, id] : employees.salaries)  
        std::cout << "Salary: " << salary << "\t\t Name: " << employees.getNamebySalary(salary) << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto& [name, id] : employees.names)  
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << "\t\t Salary: " << employees.getSalaryViaName(name) << '\n';
}
```

Will not work with double names / salaries. That would need to be reworked. Also, slow update . . .

Please comment, if that is not what you expected. In that case I will delete the answer.

Comment: How can I update the salary of a person? For example, Paul gets a raise to 500.

Comment: I have one additional question. What happens with non-unique salaries?

Comment: In this software example it will not work. It is only a first idea. One solution could be to use a ````std::map<std::pair<Salary,ID>, ID> salaries{};```` If you are really interested in such kind of solution, I will modify my answer.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://pastebin.com/BHpxRpQC) help? Note that it is a really naive, unsecure, and unoptimized implementation. Consider it a proof of concept, not a complete solution.